# Logistic regression model; too many independent variables? (listening duration of music genres)

Tags: regression, logistic, multinomial-distribution

I'm building a logistical regression model to predict the gender of users based on listening duration of music genres. My main worry is that I have over 40 different genre's and I'm concerned that having that many independent variables is going to hurt my GLM, or make it uninterpretable.

Is there a better way to approach the problem?

Comment: You maybe risk a lot of multicolinearity.  There is also the risk of quasiseperation.  I think if prediction is your main goal, adding a penalty term should take care of both of these worries.

Comment: @pr1g11 I would also caution you that by including that many variables will make you capitalize on the chance that a couple of your variables will be statistically significant by chance alone.

Comment: Lasso and ridge should work, but if you use those you can't perform inference.  What is most important to you right now: inference of prediction?

Comment: My main aim is to build a predictive model so maybe this is the best way to tackle the problem. My current game plan is to split my data into training and test sets (using cross validation techniques), run the LASSO regularisation and then perform the GLM on the variables which the Lasso doesn't reduce to zero. Without seeing my data, does that sound like a reliable methodology? Thanks for the help btw @DemetriPananos

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that is the best way to go about things.  You should a) Split into training and test.  Don't touch the test set.  b) use cross validation to select the best regularization strength.  Don't just select the non 0 parameters, you can still get a good fit when variables are left in the model. c) Once you've selected the best regularization strength via CV, estimate your out of sample error using the test set.  Create a confidence interval for the loss.

Comment: Quick update: A) I split my data into a test and training set ensuring that both had equal proportion of genders. B) I used `cv.glmnet` from the package `glmnet` to run a cross-validation for lasso (`alpha=1`,`folds=10`). C) I used the `lambda.1se` value as my regularisation strength factor and predicted the test set. D) I used the misclassification rate to test its out of sample error and compared that to my first GLM model which included all the variables. The predictive accuracy went from 69% to 74%. Does this now sound like a more reliable methodology?  @DemetriPananos thanks again!

Comment: Yep sounds good to me

Answer (score 0):

If a categorical input has too many levels, in your case too many genres, you can use a statistic trick `collapsing categories by thresholding`. For example you can use the zip codes to map to several relevant demographic variables such as median home value, however, the levels of zip codes are too many.

Collapsing categories by thresholding method require a minimum number of cases in a level in order to create a dummy code input for that level. For example, you can do the count of each genre, if the count is below a certain value, you can collapse with another genre and give a "new name".

Another way is to collapse genres by background knowledge, if you think pop and hip-pop are similar, you can just collapse them in one genre.

Hope this helps. Reference is from the statistical learning book.

Comment: Projecting zip code onto median family income per zip code is better than collapsing zip codes.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use penalized logistic regression.**

To learn more, see these threads: [What is penalized logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216187/what-is-penalized-logistic-regression) and [Penalized Log-Likelihood - Logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253426/penalized-log-likelihood-logistic-regression?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Just just run the model with all the independent variables, and 5 have come out as significant. I could run a stepwise backward regression, and only keep the variables which are significant. These are also the variables which correlate to the target variable. Is this bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have 40 predictor variables of the same type, all measuring duration of listening. Maybe these would be similar for similar musical genres ... indicating that the 40 variables do not give 40 independent pieces of information. I think this is a good case for using regression on principal components.

So start with a PCA (Principal Component Analysis) of your prediction variables, and use a few of the most important PCs as predictors. The PCA of the predictors by itself could also give useful information.

Some similar maybe relevant questions:

- [Logistic PCA and the train/test split](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/473759/logistic-pca-and-the-train-test-split)
- [Relationship between "Logistic regression + L1 regularization" and PCA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/300671/relationship-between-logistic-regression-l1-regularization-and-pca)
- [Averaging Likert Scales and PCA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/443095/averaging-likert-scales-and-pca)

Answer (score 0):

Random effects (e.g. a random effect of genre on the intercept and/or on gender) are one option here, where smaller categories (i.e. genres with fewer data points) would be shrunk towards the average genre and larger ones (with more data points) are subject to less shrinkage. One can also approach this with multiple hierarchy levels if some genres are related at some higher level and others are not. Random effects are still pretty interpretable (it's really just a form of data informed shrinkage for regression coefficients), so it's an option for both inference and prediction.

If you goal is solely prediction and you don't care so much about interpretability, there's quite few other options usually to do with how you represent the input:

- Embeddings: e.g.

  - embedding layers within a neural network either trained during training a neural network that you use for this task,
  - taken from such a NN but used in a different model, or
  - trained with some other target & then used, could e.g. be

    - predicting which types of genres get played together on the same radio station
    - the embedding for the genre name from a large language model (or just something like word2vec)
    - anything else that already exist or that you could do
- Target encoding (kind of a form of random effect, where you reduce a categorical variable to some kind of - possibly regularized - summary of the outcome split by the categories, requires careful definition/handling to avoid overfitting/target leakage)
- Frequency (or some other encoding): use the count of how often the genre is listened to as a numeric representation

Plus, if you primarily want to predict, you also don't need to necessarily use a GLM, but various other models (e.g. LightGBM, neural networks, ensembles of these etc.) could be options.